# PostgreSQL update column B with values generated from function that uses values from column A

Tags: postgresql

Pretty new to SQL.

I have a table (`client_info`) in PostgreSQL (v11.1) that includes the following columns:

```
+----------+------------------+
| clientip | clientip_country |
+----------+------------------+
|  8.8.8.8 | null             |
|  1.1.1.1 | null             |
|  4.4.4.4 | null             |
+----------+------------------+
```

I'm trying to create a function/script that will lookup the country ISO code for each `clientip` using a local install of the MaxMind GeoLite2 database and then update the corresponding `clientip_country` with the result to give:

```
+----------+------------------+
| clientip | clientip_country |
+----------+------------------+
|  8.8.8.8 | US               |
|  1.1.1.1 | AU               |
|  4.4.4.4 | US               |
+----------+------------------+
```

What's the best way to go about achieving this?

For example I'm able to retrieve the country ISO code of an IP using the following [bash command](https://maxmind.github.io/libmaxminddb/mmdblookup.html):

```
$ mmdblookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb -i 1.1.1.1 country iso_code | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
AU
```

What direction should I be looking to? An SQL command that queries the GeoLite2 DB? Or a bash script that queries the Postgres DB and updates the `clientip_country` column with the results?

Comment: It will be too time-expensive to call an external tool for each record. Download CSV version and import it into (this or separate datatbase) tables, then update your table data using one simple query.

Comment: .. or remove this field from the table at all and obtain the country in the query when it needs.

Comment: I agree with Akina. Download the CSV version of the GeoLite2 database, import into a table in your Postgres database and use a simple UPDATE statement to do the update.

Comment: @Akina Importing the CSV version sounds like a good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On @Akina's and @a_horse_with_no_name's advice I downloaded & imported [MaxMind's GeoLite2 Country database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) (in CSV format) using the following:

```
create table geoip_blocks (
    network cidr,
    geoname_id bigint,
    registered_country_geoname_id bigint,
    represented_country_geoname_id bigint,
    is_anonymous_proxy bool,
    is_satellite_provider bool
);

copy geoip_blocks from 'C:\tmp\GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv4.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
copy geoip_blocks from 'C:\tmp\GeoLite2-Country-Blocks-IPv6.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;

create index geoip_blocks_network_idx on geoip_blocks using gist (network inet_ops);

create table geoip_locations (
    geoname_id bigint,
    locale_code varchar(2),
    continent_code varchar(2),
    continent_name varchar(255),
    country_iso_code varchar(2),
    country_name varchar(255),
    eu_member bool
);

copy geoip_locations from 'C:\tmp\GeoLite2-Country-Locations-en.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

then ran an `UPDATE` to populate my `clientip_country` column with the appropriate 2 letter ISO country code using the `clientip` column data:

```
update
    client_info
set
    clientip_country = country_iso_code
from
    geoip_blocks
    inner join geoip_locations on geoip_blocks.geoname_id = geoip_locations.geoname_id
where
    network >>= client_info.clientip::inet
    and clientip_country is null;
```

Took a couple of minutes to update just over 100,000 records. Nice.